# Prevent text and value from changing when clicked twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am trying to prevent the text and value changing when clicked multiple times.  i have looked at similar questions and tried out their answers but nothing has worked.

Here is my code:

```
 const updateSuccess = (event) => {
  if (playerXTurn === true) {
    $('#cell0').val('X')
    $('#cell0').text('X')
  } else {
    playerXTurn === false
    $('#cell0').val('O')
    $('#cell0').text('O')
  }
  playerXTurn = !playerXTurn
  getGames.game.cells[0] = $('#cell0').val()
  event.stopPropagation(updateSuccess)
}
```

I also have this code before it

```
const onUpdateGame = function (event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      const data = getGames
      api.updateGame(data)
      .then(gameUi.updateSuccess)
      .catch(ui.fail)
    }
```

Comment: Add a "state" of the "click action" and check the "state" before you change text and value.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I figured it out myself